# jQuery Not Taking Effect No Matter the Placement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't get my jquery to work no matter where I put the link, despite having the code perfectly copied from my textbook. I'm new to jQuery so it's probably something incredibly simple but I'd highly appreciate any help.

In this sandbox I have three squares and would just like to hide the red square upon clicking it. It's very minimal so I hope you don't mind the external link
https://72eqp.csb.app/

```html
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='red' class='square'></div>
<div id='blue' class='square'></div>
<div id='yellow' class='square'></div>
    
<script type='text/javasript' src='main.js'></script>
</body>
```

```js
// main.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#red").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Other people I've asked tell me not to use jQuery because it's legacy and other frameworks are more effective, and I'll definitely do that, but for now I really want to use some of the tools I see in jQuery because the barrier to entry isn't too great and I have a website done already that I'd really like to stylize.

Comment: `$("#redDiv").click(function(){
      $("p").hide();
    });`

Comment: you want solution in codesandbox?

Comment: its working fine, maybe the problem is in codesandbox ! here check in codepen: https://codepen.io/am-77/pen/LYpgNze

Comment: Please include your code here, not on an external site.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have a typo in `<script type='text/javasript' src='main.js'>`. It should be `text/javascript` but then again, the `type` attribute is redundant anyway so just remove it. Notice how there isn't one on the jQuery `<script>` tag